# Does having a Microsoft SQL Server 'LocalDB' on your computer use up CPU resources?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

I've just installed `VS2013 Premium` on my `Win8.1` and noticed this in my `Sql Server Object Explorer` ..

[image]

Does this mean that I have Sql Server running as a service and therefore consuming CPU, etc?

How can I confirm this please?

UPDATE:

here's a screenshot of my task manager..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, LocalDB instances are started as needed rather than running as a service.

> Instead of installing a service and configuring security, they just start up an instance of this new LocalDB runtime as needed.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

LocalDB is a special instance of SQL Server, so to confirm whether its taking up any resource all you need to do is check if SQLServer is running in Task Manager.